# C#: Combine two elements of the SAME list (no duplicates)

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of objects.

These objects have among other elements one string called "reference". The list might look like this:

```
|reference| description |
|123      | this should |
|124      | sth         |
|125      | sth         |
|123      | be one      |
```

I want to combine WITHIN this list all elements with the same reference.
Result should be:

```
|reference| description       |
|123      | this should be one|
|124      | sth               |
|125      | sth               |
```

into a new list. So far I could only find solutions on how to group or how to combine two lists.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your set up code to make it easy for someone to create you a solution and test the results and show you a minimal working example?

Comment: Using `.GroupBy` to group the matching elements into one group and then aggregate them into a new item, you can do this: `items.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.reference).Select(g => new Item(g.Key, string.Join(" ", g.Select(e => e.description))))`

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I did try it for a few days and had no luck. In the question I did not post the code since it is so much more complex and I wanted to focus on that very question. I thought that way others may profit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can use an anonymous object or generate a new list of the type of yourclass...

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<YourClass>()
    {
        new YourClass{Reference = 123, Description = "this should"},
        new YourClass{Reference = 124, Description = "sth"},
        new YourClass{Reference = 125, Description = "sth"},
        new YourClass{Reference = 123, Description = "be one"},
    };
    
    var combined = list
        .GroupBy(item => item.Reference)
        .Select(group => new YourClass
        {
            Reference = group.Key, 
            Description = string.Join(" ", group.Select(element => element.Description).Distinct())
        });
        
    Console.WriteLine(combined);
}

class YourClass
{
    public int Reference {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should group them according to reference field and concatenate the descriptions.

Something like this should work

```
var results = list
              .GroupBy(i => i.Reference)
              .Select(g => 
                  (Reference: g.Key, 
                   Description: string.Join(" ", g
                       .Select(i => i.Description)));
```

Comment: This is already very close! Sometimes I have duplicate descriptions. In that case I want the description to be shown only once. Can I modify your answer to concatenate only if descriptions are not the same?

Comment: Go ahead, there should be a distinct in there within the `Join()` to address that.